# How to move a distributed user on NIS to local computer and disconnect NIS server

Tags: networking, ubuntu, administrator

Basically, my computer is a NIS client and my account is a distributed NIS account(not a local one) and I need to log in it. Currently, there is NIS service on my computer and I can't log in once I disconnect the network and/or connect to some other network where my NIS server is not present.

so I guess I need to be able to:

1. Log in my account on my computer when there's no network or connected to a new network.
2. I can continue to use the home dir and all the data, settings, permissions, etc... of my NIS account
3. NIS server shouldn't interfere if I need to connect back to my original network(i.e. the network with NIS server).
4. I am allowed to remove the NIS client on my computer if necessary.
5. I'd like to keep my distributed account alive since sometimes I probably need to log onto other computers within the NIS network.
6. This computer is going to be back to the NIS network in 3 ~ 6 months.

Note:

- Currently, I don't have access to the NIS server. (maybe I can request it? I'm not sure)
- My computer is Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I'm thinking to remove the NIS client and add a user with the same name and password (same uid possibly?) on the computer in order to use the /home dir but... I worried that this can't work.

Answer (score 0):

NIS does not change the overall login process and doesn't even issue any network credentials, all it does is provide another source to query the 'passwd' and 'group' tables from.

So first add an account with the same name, same UID & GID, and same home directory to your `/etc/passwd`. If you have NIS access right now, this could quickly be done using:

```
getent passwd MYUSERNAME >> /etc/passwd
```

(If you don't have NIS access, then log in as root; figure out your UID through `ls -l /home`; and use that information with `useradd`.)

This won't copy secondary group memberships (which go in /etc/group) but they probably won't be necessary for locally stored files anyway. You should also verify using `getent initgroups MYUSERNAME` that the local account isn't interfering with NIS group lookup.

A network that uses NIS most probably just dumps the password hashes into NIS as well (for everyone to see), so copy yours into `/etc/shadow` as well:

```
getent shadow MYUSERNAME >> /etc/shadow
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the `getent shadow <username>` is empty, what should I do?

Comment: Also, should I change nsswitch.conf? Looks like my computer takes a really long time to boot when it gets disconnected to network, most like it is looking for NIS server when boot.